# Slide out content boxes, remembering last active box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid with 8 grid items (only 6 are visible by default), it goes like:

- Grid item (one third)
- Grid item (one third)
- Grid item (one third)
- Grid item (one whole)
- Grid item (one third)
- Grid item (one third)
- Grid item (one third)
- Grid item (one whole)

The "one third" grid items each contain an image and hidden content embedded in a `<script type="text/template" />`, when a "one third" grid item gets clicked it will populate it's closest "one whole" grid item with the hidden content, then slide down revealing the content.

It works fine, if I click an image the content will slide down, if I click it again it will slide back up. The problem is when I click the first image then click the second image, it's not aware a different image is clicked so the new content is placed in the "one whole" grid item but it slides back up as if it were the same image clicked.

Ideally I'd have it like so:

- Click first image -> Content slides out
- Click second image -> Old Content slides up, then new content slides out
- Click second image again -> Content slides up

I have a CodePen of this slimmed down setup [here](http://codepen.io/tomblanchard/pen/pjKrXo) (ignore the minified CSS).

If you'd prefer to just check out the JS you can do so here:

```
var Feature = (function () {

  var _dom = {
    $feature: $('.js-feature'),
    $trigger: $('.js-feature-trigger'),
    $content: $('.js-feature-content'),
    $placeholdWrap: $('.js-feature-placehold-wrap')
  };

  var init = function () {
    _bindFeatureClick();
  };

  var _bindFeatureClick = function () {
    _dom.$feature.on('click', function() {
      var $feature = $(this);
      var $trigger = $feature.find(_dom.$trigger);
      var $content = $feature.find(_dom.$content);
      var placehold = $feature.attr('data-feature-placehold');
      var $placehold = $(placehold);

      $placehold.html( $content.html() );

      _revealContent($placehold); 

      return false;
    });
  };

  var _revealContent = function ($placehold) {
    var $placeholdWrap = $placehold.closest(_dom.$placeholdWrap);
    var placeholdHeight = $placehold.outerHeight();

    if( $placeholdWrap[0].style.maxHeight ) {
      $placeholdWrap.parents('.collapsible').removeClass('is-active');
      $placeholdWrap.css( 'max-height', '' );
    } else {
      $placeholdWrap.parents('.collapsible').addClass('is-active');
      $placeholdWrap.css( 'max-height', placeholdHeight );
    }
  };

  return {
    init: init
  };

})();

Feature.init();
```

The main thing is making the module aware that a new image has been clicked, then compare the old image with the new image and if it's different then run a certain function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i tweaked your code a little bit..
Now i am hiding the content field on a condition when it is not hidden and the content of the `$placehold` is same as of `$content`, and i have interchangd the position of the execution of

```
_revealContent($placehold, $content.html()); 
$placehold.html( $content.html() );
```

Updated Code:

```
$(function () {

  var Feature = (function () {

    var _dom = {
      $feature: $('.js-feature'),
      $trigger: $('.js-feature-trigger'),
      $content: $('.js-feature-content'),
      $placeholdWrap: $('.js-feature-placehold-wrap')
    };

    var init = function () {
      _bindFeatureClick();
    };

    var _bindFeatureClick = function () {
      _dom.$feature.on('click', function() {
        var $feature = $(this);
        var $trigger = $feature.find(_dom.$trigger);
        var $content = $feature.find(_dom.$content);
        var placehold = $feature.attr('data-feature-placehold');
        var $placehold = $(placehold);

        // Change Here
        _revealContent($placehold, $content.html()); 
        $placehold.html( $content.html() );


        return false;
      });
    };

      // Change Here
      var _revealContent = function ($placehold, a) {
      var $placeholdWrap = $placehold.closest(_dom.$placeholdWrap);
      var placeholdHeight = $placehold.outerHeight();

      // Change Here
      if( $placeholdWrap[0].style.maxHeight && a==$placehold.html() ) {
        $placeholdWrap.parents('.collapsible').removeClass('is-active');
        $placeholdWrap.css( 'max-height', '' );
      } else {
        $placeholdWrap.parents('.collapsible').addClass('is-active');
        $placeholdWrap.css( 'max-height', placeholdHeight );
      }
    };

    return {
      init: init
    };

  })();

  Feature.init();

});
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPaOdW